# Infinispan : Remote Second Level Cache for Hibernate (JPA)

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jpa, infinispan

Does **Infinispan** support **Distributed** and **Remote Second Level Cache** for
**Hibernate** when using **JPA**?

Would you please give me the necessary **Maven dependencies** and the needed **settings in persistence.xml**? Any other necessary settings (orther files) mentionned in your answer would be so appreciated.

**EDIT 1**

Why the downvotes? You can check [this link](http://infinispan.org/docs/6.0.x/user_guide/user_guide.html#_using_infinispan_as_remote_second_level_cache) no settings are mentionned.
**Would you please justify your downvotes?**

**EDIT : Details**

What are the needed properties in persistence.xml to set the L2 cache in a remote cluster/node?

```
<property name="..." value="..." />
```

Thank you a lot!

Comment: What's wrong with having a look at the Infinispan site? It took me less than two minutes to find this link ["Maven users"](http://infinispan.org/docs/7.0.x/getting_started/getting_started.html#_maven_users). There is also a quick start tutorial you can download and use as reference.

Comment: Thank you for the dependency sir. I hope it is the only needed one. So what about the property name that would have as a value the node IP address?? **<property name="..." value="..." />**. Because in my case, the node is remote, so the cache is not in the same JVM as it's explained in the doc. Thank you!

Comment: I don't understand the down votes.

Answer (score 0):

All your questions are answered in the Infispan [User Guide](http://infinispan.org/docs/6.0.x/user_guide/)

For the Maven dependencies have a look here [Maven users](http://infinispan.org/docs/6.0.x/getting_started/getting_started.html#_maven_users).

Using a remote second level cache is not recomenended but if you realy need it 
have a look at the [advanced configuration section](http://infinispan.org/docs/6.0.x/user_guide/user_guide.html#_advanced_configuration_2).
There you have the option to provide a cache configuration file.

Another option is to configure your (Remote)CacheManager in your `server.xml` reference
it [via JNDI](http://infinispan.org/docs/6.0.x/user_guide/user_guide.html#_configuration_12)

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answer. Where can I find "server.xml"?

Comment: The `server.xml` file is located in the Tomcat configuration directory. For other environments either have a look at the documentation how to configure JNDI resources or use the possibility to provide cache configuration file name where you can put in all that advanced configuration stuff.